# 2012 Moderator Election: Town Hall Chat

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  As Rebecca is on vacation at the moment, I shall be the one to work with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

***The Town Hall Chat took place Wednesday the 13th at 15:00:00Z UTC. A digest of the chat can be found [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest).***

---

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the primary phase.  This means that I am looking at the 11th-13th. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=rpg.stackexchange.com).  I will update this post with a direct link to the chat room once the event is scheduled.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: How about not the 6th; I'm traveling that day... Should be back home by the 7th.

Comment: @mxyzplk My bad. It is supposed to be 11-13th (same range as the SO one, but we'll of course try to schedule them at separate times). The 6th would be right in the middle of the nomination phase, nevermind it being tomorrow.

Comment: Where do I sign up to get an email about when this is scheduled?

Comment: @F.RandallFarmer When the event is scheduled, I will be updating this post. Since we're shooting to go as early as Monday, scheduling should ideally be done by Monday, so keep an eye out then.

Comment: This is very frustrating. I don't have a text-entry box at the bottom of the chat window, nor do I show up as logged in or have my photo...

Comment: Somehow, visiting the check page cleared the problem. That's a bug.

Comment: @F.RandallFarmer for future reference that's an indication that you are not logged in on the chat server

Comment: @wax eagle, It was a bug (the bad display Seemed t o indicate that I was logged in due to bad CSS. Apparently it has been fixed.